# Is there a simple image tool on mac to read alpha value of a pixel?

Tags: macos, images, adobe-photoshop, image-editing, image-processing

I am looking for a simple tool that will let me read the RGB and alpha (A) values of a pixel in an image.

Something like DigitalColor meter but that returns alpha values.

I know this is possible in photoshop but I am looking for a lightweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X has ImageMagick, right?

```
$ convert Downloads/photo.png -crop 1x1+9+96 txt:-
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,rgba
0,0: (  0, 74,117,251)  #004A75FB  rgba(0,74,117,0.984314)
```

The idea is to crop around a specific pixel, then output it to the special `txt:` format, with an output file name of `-` which is of course standard output.

You can leave out the the `-crop 1x1+X+Y` business to just get a listing of all pixels. Also note that you image must have an alpha channel for this to work, otherwise it just won't get included.

Comment: thanks but i am looking for a graphic tool. although this looks cool if you are scripting it would be cumbersome otherwise. something like an eyedropper tool would be ideal.